# Como fazer Cifra de cesar

Tags: java

Quando colo (ABCDE) com deslocamento 5 ele encripta (FGHIJ), quando na verdade deveria fica (EFGHI). já tentei de tudo de não consigo resolver. No caso ele ta fazendo o deslocamento seguinte a minha entrada.

```
package cifracesar;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cifracesar {

public static String encriptar(int chave, String texto) {
    StringBuilder textoCifrado = new StringBuilder();
    int tamanhoTexto = texto.length();

    for (int c = 0; c < tamanhoTexto; c++) {
        int letraCifradaASCII = ((int) texto.charAt(c)) + chave;

        while (letraCifradaASCII > 126) {
            letraCifradaASCII -= 94;
        }

        textoCifrado.append((char) letraCifradaASCII);
    }

    return textoCifrado.toString();
}

public static String decriptar(int chave, String textoCifrado) {
    StringBuilder texto = new StringBuilder();
    int tamanhoTexto = textoCifrado.length();

    for (int c = 0; c < tamanhoTexto; c++) {
        int letraDecifradaASCII = ((int) textoCifrado.charAt(c)) - chave;

        while (letraDecifradaASCII < 32) {
            letraDecifradaASCII += 94;
        }

        texto.append((char) letraDecifradaASCII);
    }

    return texto.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("*****************************************************");

        System.out.print("Informe o texto a ser criptografado: ");
        String texto = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Informe a chave de deslocamento: ");
        int chave = entrada.nextInt();

        String textoCriptografado = encriptar(chave, texto);
        String textoDescriptografado = decriptar(chave, textoCriptografado);

        System.out.println("\n\nTEXTO CRIPTOGRAFADO: " + textoCriptografado);
        System.out.println("TEXTO DESCRIPTOGRAFADO: " + textoDescriptografado);

        System.out.println("*****************************************************");

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("A chave de deslocamento foi informada incorretamente.");
        System.out.println("Execute o programa novamente e entre com uma chave valida.");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve considerar que os índices começam em 0 e não em 1. Logo, se a chave de deslocamento desejada é 5, o número utilizado para deslocar o caractere deve ser 4. Altere a seguinte linha do método `encriptar`:

```
...
int letraCifradaASCII = ((int) texto.charAt(c)) + chave;
...
```

Para:

```
...
int letraCifradaASCII = ((int) texto.charAt(c)) + (chave - 1);
...
```

E do método `decriptar`:

```
...
int letraDecifradaASCII = ((int) textoCifrado.charAt(c)) - chave;
...
```

Para:

```
...
int letraDecifradaASCII = ((int) textoCifrado.charAt(c)) - (chave - 1);
...
```

Comment: Poxa cara, valeu tinha pensado em tanta coisa, mas tinha me esquecido do índice vlw.

Comment: Normalmente na cifra de Cezar, `z` mapeia para `a` com chave 1. Também creio que não seja necessário fazer o cast do caracter para inteiro